# OSX command line app linker error

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode5

I have created an OSX command app in Xcode 5

Here is the main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ConnectionListener.h"
#import "SOMatrix.h"


    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {

        @autoreleasepool {


            NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

            print_m();


        }
        return 0;
    }
```

and here is my header file:

```
#ifndef __GDC1__SOMatrix__
#define __GDC1__SOMatrix__

#ifdef __cplus
#include <iostream>
#endif

int print_m();


#endif /* defined(__GDC1__SOMatrix__) */
```

And here is a partial listing of the SOMatrix.mm file

```
#include "SOMatrix.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int print_m() {

    // logic removed to keep it short; no compile time error
    return 0;
}
```

When I build the project I got a linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_print_m", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don't understand why the function is showhow changed to have a leading underscore in the name ('_print_m').

Why this error occurs? Do I need to add the .mm file explicitly to the project?

Comment: Yes, you have to compile the `.mm` file and link it with `main.m`.

Comment: You also don't need to double "`#include <iostream>`" in your .mm file, since it's already included in the .h file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change these lines:

```
#ifdef __cplus
#include <iostream>
#endif
```

to ***this*** in your .h file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <iostream>
extern "C"
{
#endif
```

with a companion:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

at the end of the .h file.

Because you are trying to access a C++ function from Objective-C, and C++ tends to do a bit of name mangling (adding the underscore, for example).  Adding the "`extern "C"`" bit allows your Objective-C code to find your C function declarations. [The answers to this related question might elaborate on things a bit better than I can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it does not fix the linker error.

Comment: I mistyped the "`#ifdef`"… it's actually "`#ifdef __cplusplus
`". You should be good to go now.